# Do astronauts take any pills to battle bone density loss?

Tags: iss, microgravity, humans, life

Is the effect of micro-gravity on bone structure similar to osteoporosis? If so, do they often take simple pills like calcium or more advance medicine such as ones listed [here](http://nof.org/articles/22)? Lastly, are they effective?

I am aware that daily workouts on the ISS are crucial. Just wondering if a medication alone could be enough to help with bone density.

Comment: Related questions on preventative, non-invasive measures against bone density loss in microgravity: [Is there any research or recommendations for a diet in microgravity?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/528/49) (2 answers), [Is it possible to prevent muscular atrophy in microgravity with proper exercises?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/187/49) (2 answers) and [What is the exercise regimen under the SPRINT program?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2438/49) (unanswered).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is commonly known as [Spaceflight osteopenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceflight_osteopenia#Countermeasures) . This results in loss of average bone density.

> Increasing dietary calcium and vitamin
>   D is a standard countermeasure for
>   osteoporosis. Clay is reportedly used
>   by NASA for retaining calcium. 
>   A variety of drug remedies currently
>   used or proposed for osteoporosis may
>   work for spaceflight, including hormone
>   therapy (estrogen and/or progestin),
>   selective estrogen receptor modulators,
>   bisphosphonates , teriparatide , and
>   others. Whether they can provide the
>   same benefits for spaceflight as they
>   do for osteoporosis is not yet known.

External source

- http://web.archive.org/web/20080403060558/http://research.calacademy.org/calwild/2005winter/stories/mud.html
- http://gravitationalandspacebiology.org/index.php/journal/article/view/337/338#page=46